# With given key-pair tuples, I need to create a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Using the key-pair tuples from my_file.txt, create a dictionary. If a key exists multiple times with different values, use the first seen value
(e.g., the first instance we encountered the key).

```
my_file = [('a', '1')
           ('b', '2')
           ('c', '3')
           ('d', '4')
           ('e', '5')]

def makehtml(fname):
with open(fname) as f:      # reads lines from a fname file
    for line in f:
        tups = line2tup(line,"--")  # turns each line into a 2 elem tuple on it's own line.
        print tups
```

How can I create a dictionary from my_file key/value pairs.  I've tried dict(my_file), but it's telling me that "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required".

Comment: Can you please tell us what you've tried and show some code ? Nobody's going to solve the whole thing for you.

Comment: You have a syntax error on the second line. Also, on lines 3, 4, 5... Can you please show the code you are actually running?

Comment: Do you get a `ValueError`? It works fine for me.

Comment: `dict(my_file)` works, as long as you fix the syntax of `my_file`...

Answer (score 0):

The `dict` constructor accepts a list of tuples as a parameter:

```
>>> my_file = [('a', '1'),
           ('b', '2'),
           ('c', '3'),
           ('d', '4'),
           ('e', '5')]
>>> dict(my_file)
{'e': '5', 'd': '4', 'c': '3', 'b': '2', 'a': '1'}
```

Edit: ahh, i got your problem. Assuming your file looks like this:

```
   ('a', '1')
   ('b', '2')
   ('c', '3')
   ('d', '4')
   ('e', '5')
```

Then this should work:

```
def makehtml(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        d = {}
        for line in f:
            key, value = line2tup(line,"--")  
            d[key] = value
    return d
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish, but I mistakenly described the file incorrectly.  It should have started as a--1\nb--2 etc.

Comment: And what is the result of `line2tup(line, "--")`?

Comment: def line2tup(line,delim):
 list_of_strings = line.strip().split(delim)
 if len(list_of_strings) > 2:
  return "This is too many list items."
 else:
  return tuple(list_of_strings

Basically I goofed and accidentally shortcutted and printed out the result of line2tup, whereas the original file was a--1\nb--1 etc.

Sorry about my formatting...I'm a stackoverflow noob...

Comment: Not the function itself haha. What are their value in your loop?

Comment: Result was ('a', '1')\n('b', '2')\n('c', '3')\n('d', '4')\n('e', '5').  Basically, I couldn't figure out how to either strip the newline or append the tuples to a list.  I'm a super beginner so thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Let's go to chat. Hang on

Comment: Oh wait.. You can't chat yet.

Comment: Result was a tuple that was on it's own line.  Hopefully that makes sense.  In any case, your assistance made the code work properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
mydict = {}
for line in open(fname):
    k, v = line.split()
    mydict[int(k)] = v
```