# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required when attempting to coerce generator function into dictionary

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, dictionary, generator

Here is the CSV file I am working with:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"

"88",18,1,"<Req TID=""34"" ReqType=""MS""><IISO /><CID>2</CID><MemID>0000</MemID><MemPass /><RequestData><S>[REMOVED]</S><Na /><La /><Card>[REMOVED]</Card><Address /><HPhone /><Mail /></ReqData></Req>","<Response T=""3"" RequestType=""MS""><MS><Memb><PrivateMembers /><Ob>0-12-af</Ob><Locator /></Memb><S>[REMOVED]</S><CNum>[REMOVED]</CNum><FName /><LaName /><Address /><HPhone /><Email /><IISO /><MemID /><MemPass /><T /><CID /><T /></MS></Response>",0-JAN-10 12.00.02 AM,27-JUN-15 12.00.00 AM,"26",667,0
"22",22,1,"<Req TID=""45"" ReqType=""MS""><IISO /><CID>4</CID><MemID>0000</MemID><MemPass /><RequestData><S>[REMOVED]</S><Na /><La /><Card>[REMOVED]</Card><Address /><HPhone /><Mail /></ReqData></Req>","<Response T=""10"" RequestType=""MS""><MS><Memb><PrivateMembers /><Ob>0-12-af</Ob><Locator /></Memb><S>[REMOVED]</S><CNum>[REMOVED]</CNum><FName /><LaName /><Address /><HPhone /><Email /><IISO /><MemID /><MemPass /><T /><CID /><T /></MS></Response>",0-JAN-22 12.00.02 AM,27-JUN-22 12.00.00 AM,"26",667,0
"32",22,1,"<Req TID=""15"" ReqType=""MS""><IISO /><CID>45</CID><MemID>0000</MemID><MemPass /><RequestData><S>[REMOVED]</S><Na /><La /><Card>[REMOVED]</Card><Address /><HPhone /><Mail /></ReqData></Req>","<Response T=""10"" RequestType=""MS""><MS><Memb><PrivateMembers /><Ob>0-12-af</Ob><Locator /></Memb><S>[REMOVED]</S><CNum>[REMOVED]</CNum><FName /><LaName /><Address /><HPhone /><Email /><IISO /><MemID /><MemPass /><T /><CID /><T /></MS></Response>",0-JAN-20 12.00.02 AM,27-JUN-34 12.00.00 AM,"26",667,0
```

So far I have written two generator functions to parse the XML data in **column E** in order to convert the XML tags and their text into a Python dictionary.  Specifically, the `flatten_dict()` function returns an iterable sequence of (key, value) pairs. One can turn this to a list of pairs with `list(flatten_dict(root)).`

That generates the following list of tuples:

```
[('ResponseRequestType', 'MS'),
('ResponseT', '10'),
 ('PrivateMembers', None),
 ('Ob', '0-12-af'),
 ('Locator', None),
 ('S', '[REMOVED]'),
 ('CNum', '[REMOVED]'),
 ('FName', None),
 ('LaName', None),
 ('Address', None),
 ('HPhone', None),
 ('Email', None),
 ('IISO', None),
 ('MemID', None),
 ('MemPass', None),
 ('T', None),
 ('CID', None),
 ('T', None)]
```

The implementation block, starting with **line 75**, returns the csv file's columns as keys and a list object with all of the row instances as values

A list of pairs L (or a iterable of pairs) can be also transposed with `zip(*L)`

My error occurs on **line 79** when I attempt to construct a dictionary on the generator function. I have reviewed several posts, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768853/more-pythonic-way-to-write-this-block-and-elimnate-valueerror-dictionary-upda) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577503/with-given-key-pair-tuples-i-need-to-create-a-dictionary).

I realize I need to pass in a set of tuples, but why I receive this error is a paradox for me. I am using Python 3.4 and Jupyter notebooks for my experimentation.

I welcome constructive (emphasis on constructive here) feedback.

```
# In[37]:

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def flatten_list(aList, prefix=''):
    for i, element in enumerate(aList, 1):
        eprefix = "{}{}".format(prefix, i)
        if element:
            # treat like dict 
            if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag: 
                yield flatten_dict(element, eprefix)
            # treat like list 
            elif element[0].tag == element[1].tag: 
                yield flatten_list(element, eprefix)
        elif element.text: 
            text = element.text.strip() 
            if text: 
                yield eprefix[:].rstrip('.'), element.text

def flatten_dict(parent_element, prefix=''):
    prefix = prefix + parent_element.tag 
    if parent_element.items():
        for k, v in parent_element.items():
            yield prefix + k, v
    for element in parent_element:
        eprefix = element.tag  
        if element:
            # treat like dict - we assume that if the first two tags 
            # in a series are different, then they are all different. 
            if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag: 
                yield flatten_dict(element, prefix=prefix)
            # treat like list - we assume that if the first two tags 
            # in a series are the same, then the rest are the same. 
            else: 
                # here, we put the list in dictionary; the key is the 
                # tag name the list elements all share in common, and 
                # the value is the list itself
                yield flatten_list(element, prefix=eprefix)
            # if the tag has attributes, add those to the dict
            if element.items():
                for k, v in element.items():
                    yield eprefix+k
        # this assumes that if you've got an attribute in a tag, 
        # you won't be having any text. This may or may not be a 
        # good idea -- time will tell. It works for the way we are 
        # currently doing XML configuration files... 
        elif element.items(): 
            for k, v in element.items():
                yield eprefix+k
        # finally, if there are no child tags and no attributes, extract 
        # the text 
        else:
            yield eprefix, element.text     


# In[75]:

from glob import iglob
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ParseError
from parsexml2 import flatten_dict, flatten_list
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree 
import csv

headers = set()
results = []
with open('s.csv', 'rU') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)        
    data = {}
    for item in reader:
        for header, value in item.items():
            try:
                data[header].append(value)
            except KeyError:
                data[header] = [value]


client_responses = data['E'] #returns a list of values
for client_response in client_responses:
     print('\n' + client_response)
    xml_string = (''.join(client_response)) #may be not necessary
     print(xml_string)
     xml_string = xml_string.replace('&amp;', '')
     xml_string = xml_string.replace('&#x0;','')
     print(xml_string)
    try:
        roots = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string) #serialization step here             
    except ET.ParseError:
        print("catastrophic failure")
        continue                

# In[79]:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-7053ec7639d9> in <module>()
----> 1 dict(flatten_dict(root))

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your `flatten_dict` code.

1. As noted by @PatrickMaupin , You are sometimes yield value like - `yield eprefix+k` - If the generator does yield this , it would `dict()` would not work on it, this could be what is causing the issue. I believe what you want there would be - `yield eprefix+k,v` .
2. You are sometimes yielding - `flatten_dict(element, prefix=prefix)` - (or the `flatten_list()` counterpart) , that would not work either. Lets take a simple example -

   ```
   >>> def a():
   ...     yield a()
   ...
   >>> for i in a():
   ...     print(i)
   ...
   <generator object a at 0x00593B48>
   ```

   As you can see , this yielded the generator object, it did not iterate over that generator object and yield the actual results. For that you would need to iterate over and yield the results manually. Example -

   ```
       if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag: 
           for k,v in flatten_dict(element, prefix=prefix):
               yield k,v
   ```

   Or from Python 3.3 onwards, you can use the `yield from` construct, to yield the values from another iterable. Example -

   ```
       if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag: 
           yield from flatten_dict(element, prefix=prefix)
   ```

   Same applies to `flatten_list()` .

Comment: Thank you, that does clarify the root cause. How did you diagnose that it was indeed the 'yield eprefix+k,v' that was needed in lieu of  'yield eprefix+k'

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you are yielding `eprefix + k` (e.g. one element), and sometimes you are yielding `eprefix, element.text` (e.g. two elements).

Probably the first thing the generator produced was a string of length three.

Comment: Ah, I am glad you also thought so - I am trying to ensure that I cover my bases when parsing. @Patrick Maupin: do you know how I would be able to ameliorate this?